# Adding fragment to another fragment

Tags: android

I'm trying to add fragment to another fragment but I am getting the following exception:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.domain.app/com.domain.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d00a1 (com.domain.app:id/container) for fragment FrontFragment{259d9bc #0 id=0x7f0d00a1}
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d00a1 (com.domain.app:id/container) for fragment FrontFragment{259d9bc #0 id=0x7f0d00a1}
```

The activity layout:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name=".MainFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/main_fragment" />
```

The fragment layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

How I am trying to add the child fragment from the MainFragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);

    // If there is no saved instance state, add a fragment representing the
    // front of the card to this activity. If there is saved instance state,
    // this fragment will have already been added to the activity.
    getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PassbookViewerFrontFragment())
            .commit();

    return rootView;
}
```

As far as I can tell, the id I am providing to the FragmentManager exists and should be there. Any hints on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: pass the id of the layout of activity containing the first fragment in add(R.id.container, new PassbookViewerFrontFragment())

Comment: But I need it to be added to the Fragment as it's when I want my whole logic. This activity is just a dummy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in the activity layout I had a `<fragment id="@+id/fragment">` declared with an id already and this id took place instead of the `container` id I had on the fragment layout.
Short story short: either no id on the `<fragment>` or a wrapper layout in the fragment.

Also, doing the FragmentTransaction inside the `onCreateView` works.

Answer (score 0):

You inflated layout-resource, but view not created at moment, when you try to add nested fragment. Replace this code:

```
getChildFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new PassbookViewerFrontFragment())
        .commit();
```

To another method, which is called after `onCreateView`

Comment: I added a Button to the main fragment and placed the transaction in that button's click listener. Naturally doesn't produce an error inflating main activity but when i click the button, i still get the second exception saying no view found for the id container.

Answer (score 0):

Your `FrameLayout` **MUST** be in your `activity layout` in order for this to work. This is because the `FrameLayout` in which you want to place your child fragment must be inflated before it can be populated. By including it in your `main_fragment.xml` layout, when calling `inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment)` the frame layout will get inflated as well, which is then ready to be filled with the child fragment.

In a nutshell, delete your child fragment layout xml file, then put this in your main_fragment layout:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name=".MainFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/main_fragment">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</fragment>
```